# How to move Azure DevOps Project to another Organization with all the history?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I've got a project under my user that I want to move to my Azure DevOps Organization.

I can only see the option to move repository through Import functionality but not a Project.

I can't see any options in Azure DevOps on migrating projects.
Anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is [**`not`**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365365/make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te-1.html) supported today. But this feature is up there on the pipeline as you can see.